# Calculating angle of nearest section

Tags: java, android, math

Suppose I have a Circle. The user can touch the circle all around the edge and I am able to obtain the angle of which they touched the circle (from the center). Now, say the circle is divided by 8 sections.

So therefore at each section I would have the following:

```
section 0 = 0 degrees
section 1 = 45 degrees
section 2 = 90 degrees
section 3 = 135 degrees
...
section 7 = 315 degrees
```

So from the angle that has been touched, how can I obtain the nearest section angle? e.g if the user touched at 95 degrees, I should be able to compute 90 degrees (section 2) as the nearest section angle.

I am actually doing this on android/Java. So any utility functions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: and if they click at 40 degrees should it be segment 0? If so floor(angle / 45), otherwise probably round(angle / 45).

Comment: Not sure why this was closed... I found it very relevant and helpful. I was about to ask the same thing but I bumped into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob already pointed out in the comment the section can be found from `round(angle/45)` & the floor angle can be found from `45*(round(angle/45))`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `round` instead of `floor`? For instance, if `angle` equals 44, then your formula gives 0 degrees. But 44 is closer to 45 than 0.

Comment: @Kevin...yes I think it should be round ...please see the edits..
actually i didnt notice the word nearest.. my bad..

Comment: Yeah I used round, but this is the answer... I knew it was something simple! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Java syntax, but the following should do

```
(round((angle/360)*numSections))*360/numSections
```

The angle/numSections calculation MUST be in float AND that round MUST be round to integer; the kind of round that gives 1 for 1.4 and 2 for 1.6. Additionally you may need an additional if to convert 360 to 0.